# botframework v4: Trigger onEvent method using botframework emulator

Tags: node.js, botframework

I would like to test a new function for my chatbot, the new function will be call in the onEvent method, I would like to test it first locally using the emulator, so that it will not affect the production code while testing the new function.

Is there a way to trigger the "onEvent()" method in the botframework emulator?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any official doc about sending an event to bot emulator , but I do found a way to trigger an event in bot locally.

Firstly , this is my code , it is easy , just for monitor if the event is triggered :

```
this.onEvent(async (context, next) => {

    await context.sendActivity("event received!");

    await next();
});
```

Run my bot locally, and send a message to my bot and save chat transcript here : 
[image]

In transcript open it with notedpad ++ or some editors, find the message obj we just sent : 
[image]

Well , now we can use this json obj to send event to our local bot to trigger events using postman or restclient just change the "type" value as "event":
[image]
As you can see, the onEvent() function has been triggered successfully : 
[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi Stanley, this is really helpful. Thanks a lot.
I also added other parameter in the json object (such as "name") to specify which chatbot client trigger the event.

 added to bot code:
if(context.activity.name === "webtest"){
 await context.sendActivity("event received!");
}

json:
  {
    "text": "11111111",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "type": "event",
    "name": "webtest",

Answer (score 1):

In The BotFramework Emulator under the conversations drop down menu, there is a list of events you can send the bot. Unfortunately, there is not an option for a custom event at the moment; however, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/416) on GitHub requesting this feature and it looks like it might be addressed in the next release. Might be beneficial to leave a +1.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already knew that "conversations" drop down menu in the botframework emulator.
Thanks for the Github link I will follow the progress of these feature.